# Repeated "rsyslogd-2007: action 'action 18' suspended"

Tags: debian, rsyslog

I haven't looked at my `/var/log/messages` in a while.  It turns out to be full of messages like

```
Dec 23 06:27:01 ifs-web rsyslogd-2359: action 'action 18' resumed (module 'builtin:ompipe') [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2359 ]
Dec 23 07:17:01 ifs-web rsyslogd-2007: action 'action 18' suspended, next retry is Wed Dec 23 07:17:31 2015 [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
```

This means very little to me - I don't know what 'action 18' means.  How can I trace this further to try and find the source of the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URL http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 shown in the second message, took me to an informative thread.

**EDIT**: The content at this link has since been changed.  To show the content of this page at the time of writing, here is an [archive link](https://web.archive.org/web/20180411003625/http://kb.monitorware.com/kbeventdb-detail-id-6925.html).  The current content at http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 explains the same problem described below.

Let's ignore the "Full Description" that says this status should never be exposed to users and indicates a programming bug.  It appears that there has been some behaviour change in rsyslog and this *is* now exposed.  But it can be worked around.

> > Is there anywhere I can find out what action 18 is or how to debug what the issue is?
>
> You can name actions (name="xxx" attribute). If not named, rsyslog counts them, in load order, and assigned a name "action-", so this is the 18th action in load order.
>
> I would guess that it is a distro-default of writing to the xconsole pipe, which actually does not exist because it is not used. If so, you can simply remove that line from rsyslog.conf. Some distros do this by default, and as we get write errors, we need to report them as usual.

Another clue here is the `module 'builtin:ompipe'` in the `resume` message (i.e. it's trying to write to a pipe here, not an ordinary log file).

I was indeed running Debian Jessie, which is mentioned in the thread as having this configuration by default.  And the action number corresponded to the xconsole line.

In more recent versions of Debian the xconsole line has been removed.  The fix is introduced in version 8.14.0-2 of the Debian rsyslog package.  https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=745492#25

Answer (score 2):

Use the following for debugging:

```
rsyslogd -N 1 -d 2> /tmp/rsyslog.stderr.$$  | egrep "cnf:|ssigned|filter|ACTION|PRIFILT" | \
egrep -v 'cnf:global:script|END' | more
```

Comment: +1.  Very cool, you mean this shows me all the different ACTION numbers, and which config line they correspond to.  So I can see which config line corresponds to the problem action, e.g. in my case I wanted to know what "action 18" was.  Note to readers - this command redirects some debugging output to the file `~/0`, overwriting anything that was there already.

Comment: Never discard STDERR output that might be interesting (and unreproducible later ) by redirecting it to /dev/null. If you are concerned about overwriting previous content of an (clearly temporarily file named '0') either use the >> append redirect to direct STDERR to a process unique file for example /tmp/rsyslog.stderr.$$